# Is there a limit on the number of collectors I can create per survey?

Tags: surveymonkey

I would like to create a new email collector each time I identify a new group of respondents, create recipients and track responses for that new group or even one individual.

I have a 6 surveys that I reuse over and over again. I currently use a web link collector with custom variables and capture the email address in the survey to identify responses.  I currently use a webhook and the api to download responses.

This approach is problematic for several reasons:

- I cannot define the groups up front before I administer the survey
- I want to be able to use the collector again at a later date to administer the same survey to the same group
- email addresses are mistyped and cannot be verified to track responses over time.

Answer (score 0):

This was the response I got from the Sr. Technical Support Engineer.

> While there's no defined limit, performance implications (in terms of
>   accessing Analyze Results) are something that a large number (w/ large
>   numbers of responses) could encounter.